# Need understanding of the code for installing mongodb server in ec2-linux instance

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am hosting a mongodb server on ec2-linux instance by following some API documentation.I have not understood some lines where I need some understandings because it is very necessary to clear each step in order to clear the concepts of programming(I am a newbie).

The code that I am following is as follows:

```
$ curl -O http://downloads.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-1.0.1.tgz
$ tar -xzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-1.0.1.tgz
$ cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-1.0.1/bin
[bin]$ ./mongod --version
```

In the above stanza when I ran Last line and executing it `./mongod --version` It shows `unknown option version`, when I changed it to `./mongod --3.0/3.0.0` it displays `unknown option error`.
So how to execute this command:**./mongod --version**?

2.) How to create the mongodb datafile directory in the desired location and then run the database:

`mkdir /mnt/db
./mongod --fork --logpath ~/mongod.log --dbpath /mnt/db/`

**I have not understood this command**.What I have understood I can explain it here please correct me if I am wrong.

**My Explanation:**

1.)In my `/home/ec2-user/mongodb-linux-x86_64-1.0.1/bin`folder there is a file named `mongod`, So we are pointing that file to `./mongod --fork --logpath ~/mongod.log --dbpath` which conatins `mnt/db` folders.This is what I have understood.

Please help!
Thank you

Comment: yes, that's correct. Assuming you are in /home/ec2-user/mongodb-linux-x86_64-1.0.1/bin

Comment: but when I execute this command `./mongod --fork --logpath ~/mongod.log --dbpath /mnt/db/` it displays `unknown option fork.`

Comment: for this version --version and --fork options seems to be not available. If you are not purposefully using version 1.0.1 then you should try newer versions of mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ curl -O http://downloads.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-1.0.1.tgz
```

Curl does a HTTP request so that you're able to download mongodb.

```
$ tar -xzf mongodb-linux-x86_64-1.0.1.tgz
```

MongoDB package comes as a combined tar archive so you're opening it to a directory. (X option for extract)

```
$ cd mongodb-linux-x86_64-1.0.1/bin
```

Change directory to mongodb's bin folder.

```
$ ./mongod --version
```

Execute mongod binary with the argument --version. If that doesn't work for you, make sure your binary has executable permissions. To do that execute below command while you're in **bin** folder:

```
$ chmod +x *
```

I'll try to explain executing something on shell as its simplest, when you execute something in shell, it uses currently open terminal so you need to run your **mongod** instance as daemon to work properly. Therefore:

```
./mongod --fork --logpath ~/mongod.log --dbpath /mnt/db/
```

**--fork** option guarantees that **mongod** instance will run as daemon, and will use **~/mongod.log** for logging and of course you're setting a data path to make mongodb work.

If you get **unknown option** error, that means you're giving some wrong arguments to binary. To see which arguments are valid you can simply run

```
./mongod --help
```

Furthermore, to read more about fork [read here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) Also I would recommend you to download a newer version of Mongodb, **1.0.1** is like ancient. Current version is **3.4.4**

Executing a binary in shell possible with either one of the two ways:

- Change directory into where binary located at and use `./binary`
- Directly use `/home/sercan/binary`

Don't forget that it needs to have executable rights. As a side note `--fork` is only valid for linux.

**EDIT:** To install (curl) latest stable mongodb:

```
curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-3.4.4.tgz
```

Comment: I have executed the command `./mongod --version` but it is not executing even after getting the executable permissions.

Comment: One more thing that how can I install the latest version to 3.4.4 in this code?

Comment: You  need to find out link of 3.4.4, I've edited my answer for you